# how to execute a class (python)

Tags: python, class, oop

#I am making a program that will calculate area and perimeter or the circle. No errors but the answer is not what I expect it to be.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.radius = 0




    def setRadius(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
  



    def calcArea (self):
        self.area = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2)

    def calcCircumference (self):
        self.circumference = 2 * (3.14 * self.radius )



    def getRadius (self):
        return self.radius ()

    def getArea (self):
        return self.calcArea ()

    def getCircumference (self):
        self.calcCircumference ()
```

#My execution

```
c1 = Circle ()
print("c1.Area",c1.getArea())

c1.setRadius(7)
print("c1.Area",c1.getArea())
```

#this is the answer I get when I execute it.
c1.Area None
c1.Area None

Comment: Please check the answer I posted, if it helps please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Based on your class definition below is the code how you will get the area printed.

```py
c1 = Circle()
c1.setRadius(7)
c1.getArea()
print("c1.Area", c1.area)
c1.Area 153.86
```

- Incase you want it to be returned by calling `c1.getArea()` only, then below change in the class code would help for `c1.getArea() and c1.getCircumference()`.

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.radius = 0

    def setRadius(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def calcArea (self):
        self.area = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2)
        return self.area

    def calcCircumference(self):
        self.circumference = 2 * (3.14 * self.radius )
        return self.circumference

    def getRadius (self):
        return self.radius()

    def getArea (self):
        return self.calcArea()

    def getCircumference (self):
        return self.calcCircumference()

c1 = Circle ()
c1.setRadius(7)
print("c1.Area", c1.getArea())
print("c1.Area", c1.getCircumference())

# Below is the output
c1.Area 153.86
c1.Circumference 43.96
```

Comment: may I ask how would I execute both area and circumference ?

Comment: May I ask, why my answer was not accepted or upvoted ? I answered it first actually

Comment: I am sorry I am actually new here. It says I am not able to upvote but I can now since I earned some points from commenting.

Comment: That's okay, I have updated the code where you can execute both are and circumference

Answer (score 2):

`calcArea` and `calcCircumference` should return some values as those are used in other methods to calculate the results. Also, the `radius` is a property and not callable.

Change the class definition like below

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = 0

    def setRadius(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def calcArea(self):
        self.area = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2)
        return self.area

    def calcCircumference(self):
        self.circumference = 2 * (3.14 * self.radius)
        return self.circumference

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def getArea(self):
        return self.calcArea()

    def getCircumference(self):
        self.calcCircumference()
```

Then you will get the following results

```
c1 = Circle()
print("c1.Area", c1.getArea())  # c1.Area 0.0

c1.setRadius(7)
print("c1.Area", c1.getArea())  # c1.Area 153.86
```

Comment: how about both area and circumference?

Comment: @Mitchel - I have updated the code per your ask, please check :)